# SQL create view with sum query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following registration table

```
| EMP_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE  | PNUM |
|  1     | 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-25|  10  |
|  2     | 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-30|  30  |
```

And i want following result in view

```
| START_DATE | END_DATE  | TOTALNUM |
| 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-25|   40     |
| 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-30|   40     |
```

And i have tried to create view with sum query but no success .

Comment: What did you try? And what kind of weird date are these? 35th of October?

Comment: I don't seem to understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  create view EMP 

    as

    select  START_DATE ,END_DATE,(select SUM(PNUM) from s) TOTALNUM

    from s

    group by [START_DATE],END_DATE
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that there is no grouping but just selecting every row and show it's start & end date and the sum of PNUM of all the rows:

```
SELECT START_DATE, END_DATE, SUM(PNUM) FROM TableX
```